# No network found on new Pi 2 but works fine with B+

Tags: raspbmc, connection, pi-2, data-transfer

I have two raspberry pis. A model B+ and a new series 2. I have a home network on a windows 8 machine I have 3 external drives attached to the Pi, and with the B+ it works fine, I can transfer movies from upstairs to any of my drives downstairs, but my problem is that when I connect the pi2 I can't see the pi downstairs from the windows upstairs. The crazy thing to me is they are both set up exactly the same, except the MAC address of course.

Comment: If both Pi's share the same IP, that cannot work.

Comment: You haven't described your home network. Is it wired or wireless? What do you mean by "see"? Can you ping the RPi addresses from the Windows machine?

Answer (score 2):

As user236012 commented, you cannot have the same IP address for two different devices. This setup would only work if you only had one Raspberry Pi connected to the network at a time.